# How to add edit and display presence or absence to an event (many to many association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with webinars participants and speakers, i can select an webinar(s) for each participant, but I want to list who attended and who didn't(some of them subscribe but don't participate). I can list all subscribers but i don't know how to list who was connected and who wasn't some help please

I've tried to add 2 columns to participants connected and not_connected(boolean) but it doesn't work because i can have the same  participant in other webinars(and he can be connected). removed columns and added them to the join table i think because there are the webinar_id and participant_id I'm not sure with this and i didn't find any reference on the website

Can you help or point me in the right direction to get how is connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just track if a participant connected or not in your join table, `participant_webinars`. The code below assumes you've added `connected` as a `boolean` to `participant_webinars`.

```rb
class Participant < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :participant_webinars 
  has_many :webinars, through: :participant_webinars
end
```

```rb
class Webinar < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :participant_webinars 
  has_many :participants, through: :participant_webinars do
    def connected
      where('participant_webinars.connected = ?', true)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class ParticipantWebinar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :participant
  belongs_to :webinar

  scope :connected -> { where(connected: true) }
end
```

then use: `webinar.participants.connected`

Comment: `so i have this all ready                                                                                            
       class Participant < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :participant_webinars
 has_many :webinars, through: :participant_webinars                                         class Webinar < ApplicationRecord                                                               
        has_many :participant_webinars
 has_many :participants, through: :participant_webinars `

Comment: where is the `:participant_connections comming?

Comment: ok I have `connected` , `notconnected`  and `ascherip` in `participant_webinars`, can I define another for ascherip there are all boolean(`default false`). And also i want to to add them to My edit and new participant form as check boxes How can i do this?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but this is what i came up with `<%= f.check_box :connected, connected %>` but is not working

Comment: `<%= f.label :connected, 'Connected?' %><%= f.check_box :connected %>`

Comment: I've tried this all ready  and i get this `undefined method `connected' for #<Participant:0x18bea8c8>`

Comment: It isn't an attribute of the participant model, it's an attribute of the participant_webinars.

Comment: ok what can i do to add the `connected check_box` to the `new_participant form`?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for  :participant_webinars` in the `participant.rb` still get an error `undefined method `connected' for #<Participant:0x919c380>`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+accepts+nested+attributes+form+guide

Comment: thank you I got to this `<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.fields_for :participant_webinars do |ff| %>
 <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= ff.label :connected, 'Connected' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= ff.check_box :connected %>
     </div>
 </div>
 <% end %>` no error  but is not displaying either

Comment: hi I removed the f before fields_for and now it shows but now is not saveing, i added the params `def participant_params
    params.require(:participant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, 
      :email, :qualification, :city, :file,  
      participant_webinars: [:connected, :notconnected, :ascherip, webinar_ids: []])
  end` and in the new `@participant.participant_webinars.build` any ideas?